# Splitting a list of integers into sublists given 0 as separator

Tags: python, list

I have this list of integers:

```
l = [6, 6, 0, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 4, 6]
```

and I would have to generate the following list, by splitting the above list using consecutive zeros as a separator, in order to get:

```
res = [[6, 6], [5, 4, 5] , [4, 6]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in order to group the elements in the list that appear between `0s`:

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(l, key = lambda x: x != 0) if k != 0]
# [[6, 6], [5, 4, 5], [4, 6]]
```

---

**Details**

The `key` argument here `key = lambda x: x != 0` is transforming the list so that it is instead grouped by:

```
[x != 0 for x in l]
# [True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

Note that that `groupby` groups consecutive values that are equal.
So this key will yield the following values as a result of the `groupby`:

```
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(l, key = lambda x: x != 0)]
[[6, 6], [0], [5, 4, 5], [0, 0], [4, 6]]
```

Now we only have to specify that we want to keep the `values` if the `key` is not `0`, which can be done by adding `if k != 0` at the end of the list comprehension.

---

Helpful reads:

- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting learning python and this kind of syntax is still difficult for me!
I will check as answered as soon as I can!

Comment: Hi @Marco, added some explanations. Hope it's clearer now. Let me know if you have any doubts

Comment: This is clever. Even a non-beginner like me had to look twice to understand it. An insight that might help is that it works just as well if `key=lambda x: x == 0` !

Comment: Yes that's right @BarryRogerson the point is to group the elements by some distinctive key. Thanks :)

Comment: @yatu i think the approach i showed in my answer  is easier and cleaner, using python slicing and zip() built-in func, without loading any modules. check it out and let me know if you agree. in the end, your code work correctly as intended. good job.

Answer (score 1):

Python has an amazing feature we can use for that called slicing.
i think this approach is easier than other answer that uses itertools.groupby.

**code:**

```
l = [6, 6, 0, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 4, 6]
res = list(map(list, zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))
print(res)
```

**result:**

```
[(6, 6), (0, 5), (4, 5), (0, 0), (4, 6)]
```

**alternative using list comprehension instead of map built-in func:**

```
res = [list(i) for i in (zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))]
```

**explanation:**

**the zip()** function take iterables (like: list, string, dict), or user-defined iterables and returns an iterator of tuples based on the iterable object.

**the map()** function takes two arguments, The first argument is the name of a function and the second a sequence (e.g. a list) seq.

map() applies a function to all the elements of the sequence.

we use it here to apply list built-in function to all tuples results from zip function.

with help of **slicing**, we give zip function two iterables made from your list, one start from first item with increment of two, and other start from the second item, with also increment set to two.

**explaining slicing used here:** 
l[::2]

> Lists have a default bit of functionality when slicing. If there is no
>   value before the first colon, it means to start at the beginning index
>   of the list. If there isn't a value after the first colon, it means to
>   go all the way to the end of the list. That last colon tells Python
>   that we'd like to choose our slicing increment. By default, Python
>   sets this increment to 1, but that extra colon at the end of the
>   numbers allows us to specify what we want it to be.

**slicing tutorial:**

[link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3)

**python zip function docs:**

[link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

**python map function docs:**

[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

**python list comprehension docs:**

[link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)